# Dynamic content load from MongoDB and SEO

Tags: seo

I'm totally new to Web Development and i've made a website which load some content from Parse.com database (mongodb).

So i have a website with totally 10 html files.

2 of them load content dynamically.
1) is to load some stores from the database
2) is to load some events from the database.

All 2 of them load the content via Javascript Parse SDK.

How can i get the maximum results of Google SEO so when someone search lets say "name of my website" + " name of the store"

to get the result   http://example.com/buisnessdetails.php?id=12345

(the .php is because i have separated footer.php and head.php but generally is like an html file)

Does anyone had the same issue ?

FYI the page is http://sourtouki.gr

and a event is http://sourtouki.gr/eventDetails.php?id=oWBGcju8pA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google will see this *buisnessdetails.php?id=12345* two ways; one is as a single page with a parameter, the second is as separate pages since the results are full, complete, and hopefully unique HTML content.

Keep in mind that Google keys its index off of two primary keys; the domain name and the full and complete URL. Each complete URL that returns a complete HTML page, will be indexed providing there is no penalty applied to the content.

However, there is some danger in what you are doing.

While Google will index your page with parameters as separate URLs, the semantics of the URL is weak.

For example, the id-12345 says nothing about the content presented. However, if the id were to be id=globalmarketingenterprisesinc then that adds value.

Even better yet, it would be far better to make friendly URLs such as /business details/global marketing enterprises inc/ that uses terms and brand names from ontologies, then you will be able to rank pages for search significantly better.

Keep in mind that Google is scrutinizing dynamic and automatic content carefully these days. It is understandable that data driven content exist, it is also advisable to make the data driven content as strong as it can be and signals quality, topic strength, and value.

So while Google will index your dynamic pages they exist today, the results will not perform anyway near as well as it can without turning the results into a friendly URL. I advise exploring how to make this happen for your site.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer! Do you know if `URI.js` is going to help us with this? Or you have any better way to prupose?

Comment: @KwnstantinosNatsios I do not know about URI.js. Sorry. I have written my own CMS and have a solution there, however, it would not help you at all. I would advise asking another question with more precise details to see if there is an .htaccess or other solution/ideas for you. Give as many realistic details as you can so perhaps someone can walk you through this. For example, where do the parameters come from and what do they really look like?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37297320/htaccess-rewrite-complex-rule